# Background Segmentation React

Tags: reactjs, image-segmentation

I'm using this opensource project -https://github.com/Volcomix/virtual-background in React
and trying to change the person border color and make it thick.

Can someone please suggest me a proper approach to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.